# Doctrine entity listener not firing using YAML configuration

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony5

When i use the following annotation within an entity, the listener for it is called successfully. The problem with using the annotation rather than configuring it within the service config is that i cannot pass services into the listener through the constructor.

```
/**
 @ORM\EntityListeners({CustomerLoadListener::class}) 
*/
```

I've tried setting the listener up in services.yaml using the following snippet:

```
services:
    App\EventListener\CustomerLoadListener:
        tags:
            -
                name: 'doctrine.orm.entity_listener'
                event: 'postLoad'
                entity: 'App\Entity\Customer'
```

Here is my event listener class:

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\EventListener;

use App\Entity\Customer;

class CustomerLoadListener
{
    private CustomerService $customerService;

    public function __construct(CustomerService $customerService)
    {
        $this->customerService = $customerService;
    }

    public function postLoad(Customer $customer): void
        dd($customer);
        // Do something with customer entity...
    }
}
```

When i use the YAML config above, the listener is never called. yet the standard doctrine annotation works fine.

I want to use call the listener using the yaml variant so i can add custom arguments that are passed via its constructor.

The code works fine if i was to change the name of the event to 'doctrine.event_listener' instead of 'doctrine.orm.entity_listener'. The problem with that approach though is that the method would be called for every entity that is loaded which seems inefficient. I want it to only be called when a specific entity is loaded, which in my case is the Customer entity.

I just can't seem to figure out why when i use an entity_listener, it never seems to get called when i set it up in the yaml config.

Comment: Did you try to remove the annotation and keep the yaml config?

Comment: I did yes, it seems to completely ignore doctrine entity listeners specified when using the yaml config. In doctrine.yaml, the entity is configured to use annotations, not yaml config. I'm not sure if that has something to do with it as i see in the doctrine documentation where they have examples of listing listeners under an 'eventListeners' property.

Comment: What's strange is doctrine event listeners work fine. But i don't want that behaviour when it runs the method on every entity loaded within the request lifecycle.

Comment: I believe postLoad may not fire for an associated entity. Confirm that you are loading "Customer entity" as the root entity.

Comment: This behaviour changes from doctrine 2.5. From doctrine 2.5 and above postLoad is triggered after associations are loaded